# Chrome Extension open and close a URL in a new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome Extension I am opening a URL in a new window like so:

```
var newWindow = window.open(strURL, "_blank", "width=1000,height=1500");
setTimeout(function() {
    newWindow.close();
}, 10000);
```

When the timeout runs the window doesn't close and the error returned is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: no access
```

Any idea what's happening here and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [chrome.windows API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) to easily open or close windows.

Comment: Thanks Iván. I am aware of this however this doesn't answer my question(s).

Comment: I copied your exact code, added `var strURL = "http://localhost"` and tested your code in a Chrome extension. It ran fine both from the background script, content script and popup without any errors. I can't reproduce your problem with the code provided. Are you sure this is the part causing the error?

Comment: Thanks agrm. Use the following URL and see what happens - it should reproduce the bug:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/29.396396396396398,-95.05405405405405/@29.296396396396398,-95.04505405405405,12z/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].